# SFTP Unix Script with pub/priv keys

Tags: ssh, unix, sftp, suse

I have written a script that uses sftp to get files. The issue I am having is that it is still prompting me for a password. Before you say my ssh pub/priv key is set up wrong, when I sftp from console I do not have to enter my password. I believe I may have the script wrong. Please advise me.

Problem: 
Passwordless SFTP works in console but not in script

(SFTP uName@host) on command line connects and loads sftp

Script asks for password

```
FTPSERVER='server'
USER='uName'
FILEPATH='Path'
FILE1='File.txt'

#SFTP pull to local directory, uses ssh with public key placed on username's .ssh folder
sftp $USER@$FTPSERVER <<EOF
cd $FILEPATH
get $FILE1
bye
EOF
```

Comment: Output: 







user@host:~/folder> sh script.sh : command not found: : command not found4: : command not found5: : command not found6: ...necting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx Password:

Comment: please, rather edit your question. This is not readable. And please tell us how do you run you script.

Comment: (user@host . script.sh)

Comment: (1) Are you sure that you’re showing us an accurate representation of your script?  Of course I’m not asking you to tell us your actual user name, server name, file path and file name, but please make sure everything else is accurate.  If you want to make cosmetic simplifications, create a copy of the script, simplify *that*, then test that and tell us what happens.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2a) Please [edit] your question to show how you run the script and what happens.  As you can see, you can’t do multiple lines in a comment.  (2b) Seriously?  You’re getting multiple “command not found” error messages, and you left that as an afterthought?  You should have mentioned that in the question.  (3) Is there any involvement of Windows in your activity?  Is there any possibility that your script has Windows line endings?  Is there any possibility that your script has unprintable characters?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) It is considered best practice to use lower- or mixed-case names for your variables.  The system uses upper-case names, and you don’t want to accidentally overwrite one of them.  ***In particular,*** `USER` is a standard system variable, that should always identify your ***local*** logged-in user name.  Setting `USER` to your remote name might confuse `sftp`, causing it not to know who you are, and therefore not to be able to access your key information.